# jQuery mousewheel is not working anymore

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

Currently the latest jQuery version is 2.0.2
When I download jQuery.mousewheel 3.0.4, it does no longer work with the jQuery library because handle is not exposed for the public access. How should I modify it in order to make it work?

mousewheel handle hooker:

```
function handler(event) {
    var orgEvent = event || window.event, args = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ), delta = 0, returnValue = true, deltaX = 0, deltaY = 0;
    event = $.event.fix(orgEvent);
    event.type = "mousewheel";

    // Old school scrollwheel delta
    if ( event.wheelDelta ) { delta = event.wheelDelta/120; }
    if ( event.detail     ) { delta = -event.detail/3; }

    // New school multidimensional scroll (touchpads) deltas
    deltaY = delta;

    // Gecko
    if ( orgEvent.axis !== undefined && orgEvent.axis === orgEvent.HORIZONTAL_AXIS ) {
        deltaY = 0;
        deltaX = -1*delta;
    }

    // Webkit
    if ( orgEvent.wheelDeltaY !== undefined ) { deltaY = orgEvent.wheelDeltaY/120; }
    if ( orgEvent.wheelDeltaX !== undefined ) { deltaX = -1*orgEvent.wheelDeltaX/120; }

    // Add event and delta to the front of the arguments
    args.unshift(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY);

    return $.event.handle.apply(this, args);
}
```

jQuery handle implementation

```
jQuery.each({
    mouseenter: "mouseover",
    mouseleave: "mouseout"
}, function (orig, fix) {
    jQuery.event.special[orig] = {
        delegateType: fix,
        bindType: fix,

        handle: function (event) {
            var ret,
                target = this,
                related = event.relatedTarget,
                handleObj = event.handleObj;

            // For mousenter/leave call the handler if related is outside the target.
            // NB: No relatedTarget if the mouse left/entered the browser window
            if (!related || (related !== target && !jQuery.contains(target, related))) {
                event.type = handleObj.origType;
                ret = handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments);
                event.type = fix;
            }
            return ret;
        }
    };
});
```

Or I know using bind('mousewheel') can achieve the same effect. But I don't know how I can get the scroll up and down event property. how do I do that?

Comment: It might be be helpful to post an example on http://jsfiddle.net to illustrate the problem.

Comment: what does jsfiddle do? I thought it's for demonstration only.